# Material UI Theme - Swap primary and secondary colors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am very new to Material UI themes for React JS. I have a case where I need to change the theme colors (Primary & Secondary) based on a type that I select in the dropdown. Literally if we see Material UI [website color options](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/#color-tool). If we select both primary and secondary colors the whole website got changed in the same way my application colors also needs to change. In my case my colors are hardcoded in index.js file. I am also using the redux and storing the dropdown value based on that value I need to change/swap the primary and secondary colors.

Here is the code that I am using. Can anyone please shed some light to swap the colors...?

```js
import LoginPage from './LoginPage.js';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import store from './store';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
 "palette": {
  "common": {
   "black": "#000",
   "white": "#fff"
  },
  "background": {
   "paper": "#fff",
   "default": "#f7f7f7"
  },
  "primary": {
   "light": "rgba(76, 137, 185, 1)",
   "main": "rgba(0, 87, 155, 1)",
   "dark": "rgba(0, 60, 108, 1)",
   "contrastText": "#fff"
  },
  "secondary": {
   "light": "rgba(116, 192, 231, 1)",
   "main": "rgba(220, 23, 108, 1)",
   // "dark": "rgba(39, 116, 155, 1)",
   "dark": "rgba(200, 23, 108, 1)",
   "contrastText": "#fff"
  },
  "error": {
   "light": "#e57373",
   "main": "#f44336",
   "dark": "#d32f2f",
   "contrastText": "#fff"
  },
  "text": {
   "primary": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
   "secondary": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)",
   "disabled": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)",
   "hint": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"
  },
 },
 "typography": {
  "useNextVariants": true,
  "fontFamily": "Hind",
 },
 overrides: {
  MUIDataTable: {
   responsiveScroll: {
    maxHeight: '980px'
   }
  },
  'Mui-selected': {
   'background-color': 'red'
  }
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <CssBaseline />
   <BrowserRouter basename="/">
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/' component={LoginPage} />
     <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignupPage} />
    </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
 </Provider>
 , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Material UI provides a theme provider component that can be used at the root of your app. Changing the theme object that you pass to the theme provider will propagate the changes through out your entire app. This is the method the Material UI website used to change between dark and light mode.

The documentation for ThemeProvider can be found here:

https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#themeprovider

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the values you should retrieve them out of the store. You can create a function that takes in the color arguments and creates the theme object with it. You can then update the values in your store and recreate the theme with it.

There are probably many different ways of doing this, but I wrote a small example to show you how this can be done. From your example it looks like you're using an older version of `@material-ui/core`, but the idea stays the same. It's also better to separate a lot of this code into separate files, but for the example I just put everything in one file.

```js
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Typography, Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

const initialState = {
  primaryColor: "#FF0000",
  secondaryColor: "#00FF00"
};

const SET_COLORS = "set_colors";

const uiReducer = function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_COLORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        primaryColor: action.primaryColor,
        secondaryColor: action.secondaryColor
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  uiReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

const createTheme = colors => {
  return createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: colors.primaryColor
      },
      secondary: {
        main: colors.secondaryColor
      }
    }
  });
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  colors: state.uiReducer
});

const setColors = (primaryColor, secondaryColor) => ({
  type: SET_COLORS,
  primaryColor,
  secondaryColor
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setColors
};

const MaterialApp = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(({ colors, setColors }) => {
  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(colors), [colors]);

  const [color1, setColor1] = useState('#FF0000');
  const [color2, setColor2] = useState('#00FF00');

  const saveColors = () => {
    setColors(color1, color2);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className="App">
        <Typography color="primary">PRIMARY COLOR</Typography>
        <Typography color="secondary">SEONDARY COLOR</Typography>
        <hr />
        <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
          PRIMARY COLOR
        </Button>
        <Button color="secondary" variant="contained">
          SECONDARY COLOR
        </Button>
        <hr />
        <TextField
          value={color1}
          onChange={event => setColor1(event.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          value={color2}
          onChange={event => setColor2(event.target.value)}
        />
        <Button onClick={saveColors} variant="outlined">
          Set colors
        </Button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
});

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MaterialApp />
    </Provider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Or view it on Codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-sound-s5bhi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)